# get image url from json object (wikipedia.org)

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to recover the `original` value of the json object, but I get lost while trying to find it...

```
{
    "batchcomplete":"",
    "query":{
        "normalized":[{
            "from":"dog","to":"Dog"
        }]
        ,
        "pages":{
            "4269567":
            {
                "pageid":4269567,
                "ns":0,"title":"Dog",
                "original":
                {
                    "source":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d9/Collage_of_Nine_Dogs.jpg",
                    "width":1665,
                    "height":1463
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

this is my javascript till now but it doesn work:

```
div.innerHTML += response.pages[0].original[3].source;
```

I want to retrieve

```
 https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d9/Collage_of_Nine_Dogs.jpg
```

Im working with this javascript function

```
 fetch(url)
    .then(function(response){return response.json();})
     .then(function(response) {

      var div = document.getElementById('image');

            div.innerHTML += response.pages[0].original.source;


          })
       .catch(function(error){console.log(error);});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have your syntax for objects confused. To get `source` as your object currently it would be `response.query.pages['4269567'].original.source`

However you probably want to do this dynamically, so you could do

`Object.values(response.query.pages)[0].original.source`

Comment: Im working with `response.json();` it looks helpful your code but it doesnt fit in mines.

Comment: What is the exact ouput of `response.json()`? I have updated my answer a couple of times so I might have got it wrong the first time.

Comment: im thinking in `response.pages[0].original.source;`...but it doesnt work neither,

Comment: I've edited the question and added the js function Im working with

Comment: If your top object in your question is what `response` is when you set `innerHtml` then my answer should work. I would try `console.log` one level at a time from my answer. Do you get any error message?